# How to make a jQuery script and CSS responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my jQuery script that animates a transition page.

My problem is that I don't know how to make it responsive...
If you are going to resize it on smaller screens it just won't work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-page">
            <div class="maincontent">
                 <h1>Full Page Transition</h1>
                    <a href="#" class="back">&#8592 Back to the ARTICLE</a>
                <a class="mainlink">TRY IT NOW &#10140;</a>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="next-page">
            <div class="nextcontent">
                 <h1>Great! You're in the 2nd Page!</h1>
                  <a href="#" class="back">&#8592 Back to the ARTICLE</a>
                <a class="nextlink"> &#8592 GO BACK</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* GENERAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------*/

body {
width: 100%;
}


h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 120px;
}



/* PAGES
-------------------------------------------------*/

#main-page {
    height: 25px;
    width: 375px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #27ae60;
    display: none;
}


#next-page {
    height: 25px;
    width: 375px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    display: none;
}

.maincontent, .nextcontent {
    padding-top: 40px;
    display: none;
}

a.back{
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #dfdfdf;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 25px auto 30px auto;
    display: block;
}



a.mainlink, a.nextlink {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 13%;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;

}

a.mainlink:hover, a.nextlink:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #575757;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, complete) {
      var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
      var step = args.step;
      return this.each(function(i, e) {
        args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);
        args.step = function(now) {
          $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
          if (step) return step.apply(e, arguments);
        };

        $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
      });
    };

    $("#main-page").css("background-color", "#e74c3c");
    $("#main-page").css("height", "100vh");
    $("#main-page").css("width", "100%");
    $("#main-page").fadeIn();
    $(".maincontent").fadeIn();

    $(".mainlink").on("click", function() {
        $(".maincontent").fadeOut();
        $("#main-page").animate({
            width: "25px",
            height: "375px"
        }, function() {
            $(this).animateRotate(90);
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#main-page").fadeOut();       
        }, 1500);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#next-page").animateRotate(0, 0);
            $("#next-page").css("height", "25px");
            $("#next-page").css("width", "375px");
            $("#next-page").fadeIn();
            $("#next-page").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#27ae60"
            }, function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    height: "100vh"
                }, function() {
                    $(this).animate({
                        width: $("body").width()
                    }, function() {
                        $(".nextcontent").fadeIn(300);
                    });
                });
            });
        }, 800);
    });

    $(".nextlink").on("click", function() {
        $(".nextcontent").fadeOut();
        $("#next-page").animate({
            width: "25px",
            height: "375px"
        }, function() {
            $(this).animateRotate(-90);
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#next-page").fadeOut();          
        }, 1500);

        setTimeout(function() {
        $("#main-page").animateRotate(0, 0);
        $("#main-page").css("height", "25px");
        $("#main-page").css("width", "375px");
            $("#main-page").fadeIn();
            $("#main-page").animate({
                height: "100vh"
            }, function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: $("body").width()
                }, function() {
                    $(".maincontent").fadeIn(300);
                });
            });
        }, 1400);
    });

});
```

How can I make it responsive, so that the whole animation works even on smaller viewports ([just like this](http://goo.gl/cG9Cs0)) ?

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2juw9696/)

Comment: Maybe to shrink it you could use `transform: scale(0.x)`?

Comment: I would suggest that you do some research on how to make a responsive page, it would help you understand what potential answers are really doing to your page, and perhaps help you find a solution by yourself. Did you try anything to make the page responsive by yourself? If so, could you tell us about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not too hard. Just replace the 2 lines `width: $("body").width()` with `width: "100%"`

See the updated example:

https://jsfiddle.net/fabr3jgL/

Nice page transition btw :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting width of your `main-page` wrapper and `next-page` wrapper to fixed width `width: $("body").width()`, you have to changed it to `width: '100%'` to make it fluid.

Why `$('body').width()` won't not work: it sets it to fixed width (in pixels) and as your function is executed on click event, it cannot assign new width to your wappers on window resize.